# Select only the maximum id for a given input

Tags: mysql

I have the following `sql` query. I want to select only the `max(v.id)` and not all `v.id` for a given `p_id`.

Can you please help me?

```
SELECT
    v.id,
    u.firstname as author_name,
    u.lastname as author_surname,
FROM ps_versioning as v
INNER JOIN u_users as u ON u.user_id = v.user_id
where v.patient_id = p_id
```

Except from the accepted solution, I found another way to achieve it using `order by v.id desc Limit 1`. See the full example below:

```
SELECT
    v.id,
    u.firstname as author_name,
    u.lastname as author_surname,
FROM ps_versioning as v
INNER JOIN u_users as u ON u.user_id = v.user_id
where v.patient_id = p_id
order by v.id desc Limit 1
```

Comment: this question already exists. Have a look [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547125/sql-how-to-find-the-highest-number-in-a-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547125/sql-how-to-find-the-highest-number-in-a-column)

Comment: @zinow :- you can try  max(v.id) with group by

Comment: in which table is the p_id ?

Comment: @ThomasG It's a stored procedure and the `p_id` value is given by a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining against a sub query, assuming that the u_users table is being used to filter the ps_versioning table rows:-

```
SELECT
    v.id,
    u.firstname as author_name,
    u.lastname as author_surname
FROM ps_versioning v
INNER JOIN u_users u ON u.user_id = v.user_id
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT v.patient_id, MAX(v.id) AS max_id
FROM ps_versioning v
INNER JOIN u_users u ON u.user_id = v.user_id
WHERE v.patient_id = p_id
GROUP BY v.patient_id
) sub0
ON v.id = sub0.max_id
```

If there cannot be rows on ps_versioning which don't have a matching row on the users table then you can dispense with the extra inner join in the sub query.

```
SELECT
    v.id,
    u.firstname as author_name,
    u.lastname as author_surname
FROM ps_versioning v
INNER JOIN u_users u ON u.user_id = v.user_id
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT v.patient_id, MAX(v.id) AS max_id
FROM ps_versioning v
WHERE v.patient_id = p_id
GROUP BY v.patient_id
) sub0
ON v.id = sub0.max_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job :

```
SELECT
    v.id,
    u.firstname as author_name,
    u.lastname as author_surname,
FROM ps_versioning as v
INNER JOIN u_users as u ON u.user_id = v.user_id
where v.patient_id = p_id
AND v.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ps_versioning GROUP BY patient_id)
```