# I want to select the highest value in a given joint table

Tags: sql, join, select, max

I am working on two different tables. I want to join some of the information there and select the highest value in a particular column.
here is the code I am trying to use though not working

```
SELECT
result.matric_number, max(result.331), student.last_name, student.first_name, student.other_name
from result
INNER join student on result.result_id=student.StudentID
AND
student.Session = '2020/2021'
```

Comment: SELECT
result.matric_number, max(result.331), student.last_name, student.first_name, student.other_name
from result
INNER join student on result.result_id=student.StudentID
AND
student.Session = '2020/2021'

Comment: SELECT
result.matric_number, max(result.331), student.last_name, student.first_name, student.other_name
from result
INNER join student on result.result_id=student.StudentID
AND
student.Session = '2020/2021'....  when i used this code, it fetch a single value for the highest score but the value faetch doesnt not match with the matric number. i.e, it fetch the highest score but presented it to the wrong student

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1547125/3404097 This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research. See [ask], [Help], [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)
& the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use group by,If you are using aggregate function like max in the select statement.

Below query returns max(result) for the given group,result.matric_number,  student.last_name, student.first_name, student.other_name

```
  SELECT result.matric_number, max(result.331), student.last_name, student.first_name, student.other_name 
from result INNER join student 
on result.result_id=student.StudentID AND student.Session = '2020/2021'
group by result.matric_number,  student.last_name, student.first_name, student.other_name
```

If you want max of all the records then remove all columns in select execpt max

SELECT  max(result.331)
from result INNER join student
on result.result_id=student.StudentID AND student.Session = '2020/2021'

Comment: I did but its showing me the whole information meanwhile, I only want it to display just the highest score and the student info that correlates with the score

Comment: "You have to use group by,If you are using aggregate function like max in the select statement." False.

Comment: along with aggregate functions if you are using non aggregated column then group by is mandatory.

Comment: In this case you can use CTE with rank